# can not find <execinfo.h> when setup mlpack

Tags: c++, linux, mlpack

I tried to install mlpack in cygwin and I have already installed armadillo, but I encountered following problems:

After running cmake ../ I run the make command and here is the process:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target mlpack_headers
Moving header files to include/mlpack/
[ 0%] Built target mlpack_headers
Scanning dependencies of target mlpack
[ 0%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/dists/discrete_distribution.cpp.o
[ 1%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/dists/gaussian_distribution.cpp.o
[ 2%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/dists/laplace_distribution.cpp.o
[ 3%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/kernels/epanechnikov_kernel.cpp.o
[ 4%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/kernels/pspectrum_string_kernel.cpp.o
[ 5%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/math/lin_alg.cpp.o
[ 6%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/math/random.cpp.o
[ 6%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/optimizers/aug_lagrangian/aug_lagrangian_test_functions.cpp.o
[ 7%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/optimizers/lbfgs/test_functions.cpp.o
[ 8%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/optimizers/lrsdp/lrsdp.cpp.o
[ 9%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/optimizers/lrsdp/lrsdp_function.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/optimizers/sgd/test_function.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/tree/cosine_tree/cosine_tree.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/tree/mrkd_statistic.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/util/cli.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/util/cli_deleter.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/util/log.cpp.o
/home/Administrator/mlpack-1.0.11/mlpack-1.0.11/src/mlpack/core/util/log.cpp:24:24: 致命错误：execinfo.h：No such file or directory
#include <execinfo.h>


编译中断。
src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/build.make:425: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/util/log.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: * [src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/core/util/log.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:119: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/all' failed
make[1]: * [src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: * [all] Error 2
```

I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin's `gnulib` does not provide `execinfo.h`, possibly due to compatibility issues with the underlying (Windows) system.

From the `gnulib` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execinfo_002eh.html):

> This header file is missing on some platforms: Mac OS X 10.3, FreeBSD 6.0, NetBSD 5.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, IRIX 6.5, OSF/1 5.1, Solaris 10, Cygwin, mingw, MSVC 9, Interix 3.5, BeOS.

You may want to try a WinAPI function like [CaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Can I install execinfo.h in cygwin? I am installing a c++ library and it needs this head file.

Comment: According to the documentation, even with the header file, the implementations of the `execinfo.h` functions are just stubs. You *might* get away with it if your library includes it whimsically, but that isn't likely. Your best chance is looking for a Cygwin-specific build or a patch. What is the library's name?